# Jet stream core

Tags: meteorology, jet-stream

Why on a Polar Front Jet Stream does the core form on the tropical (warm air) side and not on the polar (cold air) side?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you add more?  I'd imagine the jet stream sets up above the gradient, as suggested by thermal wind, but perhaps some source/reference/information about your position, or examples, would help make your statement more clear?